# SVN Error: Commit blocked by pre-commit hook (exit code 1) with output: Error: n/a (6)

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, pre-commit

Some weird error cropped up suddenly outta nowhere and is preventing me from checking in my code via TortoiseSVN. I'm using a free account on myversioncontrol.com

This is on a Windows Vista system. It was working fine till earlier in the day. Any clue how to get things back to normal?

The Tortoise window shows this

```
Command: Commit  
Modified: ...\edit.php  
Sending content: ...\edit.php  
Error: Commit failed (details follow):  
Error: Commit blocked by pre-commit hook (exit code 1) with output:  
Error: n/a (6).  
Finished!:
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like myversioncontrol.com have added a pre-commit hook, or have one that is now failing.  If it's a free account, it might be you've exceeded some sort of monthly commit or bandwidth limit.  Check their terms of service and/or contact them to see what's up.

UPDATE:
I've just checked their website, and it looks like the free account is only valid for 30 days, so you might've exceeded that.  You may need to pony up the £3.50pcm or find somewhere else (Google Code is one suggestion, though there are others).

Simon Groenewolt makes a good point that you may have changed something in the control panel on their website that has turned on a pre-commit hook but where it's configured incorrectly.

Comment: Thank you Neil, Simon and Stefan - I'm not sure why, but the problem seems to have solved itself. I did mess around with the user-in-question's settings, but that didnt work at that time. Only after a day things got back to normal... ((shrugs)) - oh well! :)

Answer (score 35):

Could it be that you have not entered a commit message?
According to their [twitter feed](http://twitter.com/mvcapp): "New functionality added. Block users from committing work without writing a log message. Find in the resources section of your control panel".

Comment: Ignoring the fact that the accepted answer actually solved the OP's problem, this in my experience is the most common cause of the pre-commit hook error.

Comment: Glad I read this answer. I was stuck with this darn error to figure out the server requested a comment. An appropriate error message would have helped :)

Comment: In my case, the problem was "quotes" on message.

Comment: Perfect answer you have put a message

Answer (score 5):

A [pre-commit hook](http://wordaligned.org/articles/a-subversion-pre-commit-hook) is something that runs on the server, so this probably has nothing to do with your local setup. It could be that you changed something in a settings panel on myversioncontrol.com that is implemented using a pre-commit hook or the myversioncontrol people made an error and added a non-functioning hook.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry for "answering my own question", but I figured out a workaround... If we remove the newlines in the comment / commit message, it seems to work fine.

Comment: There are no new lines in my commit message but still it gives error....Any other work-around you could figure out?

Comment: In my case it was a "<" in my commit message

Comment: In my case it was "#" this is used for an Assembla tag legitimately but there was additional “#” characters unrelated to the tag mechanism that tripped it

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me, and it was caused the absence of a comment (should say "comment required" instead of this enigmatic error at first, right...)

Answer (score 1):

Recently I am also faced the same problem, while submitting my own WordPress plugin to the directory, Finally, i figured out and worked me,

Just add a comment/ Commit message. It will work,

I used TortiseSVN.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting following exception:

> Error: Commit failed (details follow):
>   Error: Commit blocked by pre-commit hook (exit code 1) with output:
>   Error: svnlook: Path 'trunk/Development/ProjectName' is not a file

Then first check-in all the the directories and then all the files. It will work.

Answer (score 1):

I got the error as, 
"svn: Commit blocked by pre-commit hook (exit code 1) with output:
Failed with exception: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 104."

I tried 'svn commit' after '**svn cleanup**'. And It works fine!.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add comments and associate with an artifact id with no return key at the end.
for example, [artf12345] - your comments.

Answer (score 0):

## SOLUTION for WORDPRESS PLUGINS:

I think, **get_option()** returns **FALSE** (instead of **EMPTY**). So, check your plugin. Instead of:

```
if (empty(get_option('smth')))
```

there should be:

```
if (!get_option('smth'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have encounter the same issue and found that i have forgot to prefix the commit message with project identifier. Project identifier is must in our case followed by the commit message. So at the server end it doesn't found the prefix and raised the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the solution was to remove "" (quotation mark) from commit message. Weird